# NullPointerException on onPostExecute method

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I’m having a navigation drawer for my app that contains a menu with which I can navigate between the fragments. The first fragment that i get after the app lunch is the Home which contains a listView and a footer attached in the bottom (is just for the test). The problem is when I lunch the Home fragment for the first time nothing happen and its work very well, but when I change the fragments from the navigation drawer and trying to get back the home fragment the app crash. The error log show me a null pointer Exception. Thes is my code detail

**`onCreateView` method**

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       if (v != null) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();
            if (parent != null)
                parent.removeView(v);
        }
            try {


                v =   inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_homes, container, false);

                listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.homeList);

                l = new HomeListAdapter(this, homeList);
                if(l == null)
                    Log.i("tag","null");

                listView.setAdapter(l);
            } catch (InflateException e) {
        }

        return v;

    }
```

**`onPostExecute` method**

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final String res) {

            /*try {
                jObj = new JSONArray(res);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }*/

           /* JSONArray j = null;
            try {
                j = new JSONArray(res);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }*/


            // Parsing json
             for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                 //JSONObject obj = j.getJSONObject(i);

                 Home home = new Home();
                 //String photoNews = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(obj.getString("photonews"), "UTF-8");
                 home.setNomC("Karim Ennassiri");
                 home.setPhotoP("http://i1239.photobucket.com/albums/ff509/FestusMANAFEST/iker-casillas20Wallpaper__yvt2.jpg");
                 home.setPhotoAr("http://voyage-essaouira-maroc.com/upload/apostrophe_image_(13).jpg");
                 home.setText("Chlada V2.0 Edition");
                 home.setNbrSick("5");
                 home.setNbrComm("8");
                 home.setNbrShare("0");

                 homeList.add(home);

             }

            l.notifyDataSetChanged();

            //pDialog.hide();


        }
```

**The error log**

```
10-10 09:31:30.884    2447-2447/com.example.user.unchained E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.user.unchained, PID: 2447
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.user.unchained.HomesActivity$PlaceholderFragment$FeedsTask.onPostExecute(HomesActivity.java:375)
        at com.example.user.unchained.HomesActivity$PlaceholderFragment$FeedsTask.onPostExecute(HomesActivity.java:277)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And this is exactly the line that cause the error : `l.notifyDataSetChanged();`. I notice that the error is just in the case when i'm trying to display the fragment for the secode time.

So any help please ? Thanks !

Comment: Move this code in `onPostExecute()` method. `l = new HomeListAdapter(this, homeList);
                if(l == null)
                    Log.i("tag","null");
                listView.setAdapter(l);` Because your UI is updated in that method.

Comment: But if i will do that `this` will refer to the Task and not the fragment

Comment: so you need to use `getActivity()` instead of `this`.

Comment: i talk about fragment bot activity

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this in doInBackground.

```
                @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(void... ) {
        try {

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
             //JSONObject obj = j.getJSONObject(i);

             Home home = new Home();
             //String photoNews = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(obj.getString("photonews"), "UTF-8");
             home.setNomC("Karim Ennassiri");
             home.setPhotoP("http://i1239.photobucket.com/albums/ff509/FestusMANAFEST/iker-casillas20Wallpaper__yvt2.jpg");
             home.setPhotoAr("http://voyage-essaouira-maroc.com/upload/apostrophe_image_(13).jpg");
             home.setText("Chlada V2.0 Edition"); //give some other name in getter setter for setText in Home.java. It makes not to understand whether you are using setText for textview assigning. 
             home.setNbrSick("5");
             home.setNbrComm("8");
             home.setNbrShare("0");

             homeList.add(home);

         }
```

postExecute is used to display UI. don't perform heavy operation like parsing in PostExecute.

Comment: still have the probleme